# How to write testcase for my app?

Tags: java, testcase

I am writing test case for my application. My application is a windows based application.My application is a news report app. Reporting the current update like sports live update... So when I download and run the application, while it create the database and when I insert, update, delete , edit the application, the database should be change the values. What are the sql queries to test my database ?  How to write an effective test cases  for this ?

Comment: too board, what have you written?

Answer (score 3):

The good way to write effective test cases & make the testing process more saving time and effort. Here are some points to follow while creating test cases:

> - Keep your test cases simple and easy to understand
> - Include end-user perspective
> - Provide test case description
> - Include assumptions and preconditions
> - Give the steps involved
> - Give details of the test data
> - Make it reusable and modular
> - Assign testing priority
> - Provide the expected result and post conditions

Comment: "Give details of the test data" why? I want other testers to use their own data, so we actually test with more sets of data, not with the same values over and over again.
"Assign testing priority" a test case is just a test case, priority has the requirement we're implementing. Unless you have more test cases for one requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow below points in addition of above points for effective test case writing:

1. Written test cases should have a label attached to it i.e. if test case is created for sanity or regression etc.
2. You should be able to easily sort the test cases that can also be achieved if you add labels for modules/features it covers.
3. Test cases should be descriptive enough so that any layman can execute it by reading steps.